# Why define \0 as the first element of a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

When I read [BlueZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack#BlueZ) source code, I often see `char` arrays defined like this:

```
// bluez/android/sco-msg.h
static const char BLUEZ_SCO_SK_PATH[] = "\0bluez_sco_socket";
```

What good is it to define the first element as `\0`?

Comment: It effectively hides the string from printing or copying with standard functions - Whatever the intention might be.

Comment: In Bluez, this style arrays are used like:  
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    memcpy(addr.sun_path, BLUEZ_SCO_SK_PATH, sizeof(BLUEZ_SCO_SK_PATH));

What would the socket path looks , /dev/socket/?bluez_sco_socket  ?
or it can't be seen using "ls" command ?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In your particular case this array is used as pathname for a `PF_LOCAL` socket; see [here](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez/+/5.39/android/ipc.c#201). And leading NUL is used to point that address is an abstract one. From [man 7 unix](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html):

> an abstract socket address is distinguished by the fact that
>   sun_path[0] is a null byte ('\0').

And this is the only reason why the first element is `\0`.

Comment: Might want to quote this as well, for posterity: "[T]he abstract namespace w[as] introduced with Linux 2.2 and should not be used in portable programs."